# Text to speech with female voice using java

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I wrote text to speech demo using java. It is work normally, but it doesn't speak with female voice although I set for that.

My code is like below:

```
try {
System.setProperty("FreeTTSSynthEngineCentral",
    "com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
System.setProperty("freetts.voices",
    "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
Central.registerEngineCentral("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");

SynthesizerModeDesc desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(null, "general",
    Locale.US, null, null);

Synthesizer synth = Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
synth.allocate();
desc = (SynthesizerModeDesc) synth.getEngineModeDesc();
Voice voice = new Voice("kevin16", Voice.AGE_YOUNGER_ADULT,
    Voice.GENDER_FEMALE, null);

synth.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);
synth.resume();
synth.speakPlainText(text, null);
synth.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
synth.deallocate(); }catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();}
```

How will change my code to out female's voice. Help me!

Comment: I guess you mean text to speech and not speech to text?

Comment: Yes, I mean text to speech.

Comment: @HeinMinnSoe please did you succeed to implement a female voice

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the documentation](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#what_is_freetts), I see:

> This release of FreeTTS includes:
>
> - Core speech synthesis engine
> - **Support for a number of voices:**
>
>   - an 8khz diphone, **male**, US English voice
>   - a 16khz diphone, **male** US English voice
>   - a 16khz limited domain, **male** US English voice
> - Support for importing voices from FestVox (US English only)
> - Specific support for importing CMU ARCTIC voices from FestVox (US English only)
> - **Support for MBROLA voices (downloaded separately):**
>
>   - a 16khz **female**, US English voice
>   - two 16khz **male** US English voices

So it sounds like it only ships with male voices. Perhaps if you download one of the MBROLA voices, you will get a female voice.

See also [What voices are available?](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#voices_available), which explains how to get the female voices, but notes that "FreeTTS does not support MBROLA on the Windows platform".

Answer (score -2):

```
Voice voice = new Voice("kevin16", Voice.AGE_YOUNGER_ADULT,...
```

There should be other options, Kevin sounds pretty male to me. Try a Jane or something in that direction